# Cannot get fields on right place and inside border divs, using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a box which has some settings information, I am using bootstrap, but I am not sure why I am messing it up.
I want to create something similar to this.

[image]

So I write the codes like this

```
<!-- Settings  -->
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="bSettings">
            <h2>Settings</h2>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="noticebox">    
                   <h3>HELLO WORLD HELLO WORLD</h3>
                   <p>lorem ipsum alit berket usum and amazing</p>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  active">On</button>
                   <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary  ">Off</button> 
                </div> 
        </div>
     
    </div><!-- /.borrow-settings -->
```

So bsettings is the outside box, and noticebox is the oval looking box in which everything is, I am not able to push the buttons to the right and the text on the left. I tried using bootstrap classes like pull-right and even tried dividing all those to classes like col-md-8 and col-md-4 like this

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="bSettings">
            <h2>Settings</h2>
                
                  <div class="noticebox">  
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                   <h3>HELLO WORLD HELLO WORLD</h3>
                   <p>lorem ipsum alit berket usum and amazing</p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-4">   
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  active">On</button>
                   <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary  ">Off</button> 
                   </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
```

Which breaks all the boxes on my page,
[image]
The styles I wrote for both of this classes are ,

```
.bSettings{
    border : 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
.bSettings h2{
    color: #666;
    font-size:20px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
    
}
.bSettings .noticebox{
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-radius : 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

So I need help in creating exactly like the picture provided but I guess I am mixing up bootstrap classes. And the reason I have a col-md-8 col-mdoffset-1 at the starting is because I have a side bar as well, which I am using for something else so that needs to be there. I ADDED JS FIDDLE here
https://jsfiddle.net/fne081z3/

Comment: Can you provide a js fiddle please?

Comment: @GuruTom https://jsfiddle.net/fne081z3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a row `<div class="row">` before **col-md-8** inside the **noticebox** div.

**CSS**

```
  .noticebox{
    border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
  .notice-btns{
    border-radius: 0;
    // set min-height equaling the height of noticebox
  }
  .notice-btns:last-child{
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="bSettings">
      <h2>Settings</h2>

      <div class="noticebox">    
        <div class="row">     

          <div class="col-md-8">
            <h3>HELLO WORLD HELLO WORLD</h3>
            <p>lorem ipsum alit berket usum and amazing</p>
          </div>

          <button type="button" class="col-md-2 notice-btns btn btn-primary  active">On</button>
          <button  type="button" class="col-md-2 notice-btns btn btn-primary  ">Off</button> 

        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: what does this .notice-btns:last-child mean ?

Comment: that's for the second button(last button in this case), as the first button doesn't need a rounded-border. 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp